# Is there a way to efficiently apply a function to 3 million values in a Pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am currently working on a course in Data Science on how to win data science competitions. The final project is a Kaggle competition that we have to participate in.

My training dataset has close to 3 million rows, and one of the columns is a "date of purchase" column.

I want to calculate the distance of each date to the nearest public holiday.

E.g. if the date is 31/12/2014, the nearest PH would be 01/01/2015. The number of days apart would be "1".

I cannot think of an efficient way to do this operation. I have a list with a number of Timestamps, each one is a public holiday in Russia (the dataset is from Russia).

```
def dateDifference (target_date_raw):
    abs_deltas_from_target_date = np.subtract(russian_public_holidays, target_date_raw)
    abs_deltas_from_target_date = [i.days for i in abs_deltas_from_target_date if i.days >= 0]
    index_of_min_delta_from_target_date = np.min(abs_deltas_from_target_date)
    return index_of_min_delta_from_target_date
```

where 'russian_public_holidays' is the list of public holiday dates and 'target_date_raw' is the date for which I want to calculate distance to the nearest public holiday.

This is the code I use to create a new column in my DataFrame for the difference of dates.

```
training_data['closest_public_holiday'] = [dateDifference(i) for i in training_data['date']]
```

This code ran for nearly 25 minutes and showed no signs of completing, which is why I turn to you guys for help.

I understand that this is probably the least Pandorable way of doing things, but I couldn't really find a clean way of operating on a single column during my research. I saw a lot of people say that using the "apply" function on a single column is a bad way of doing things. I am very new to working with such large datasets, which is why clean and efficient practices seem to elude me for now. Please do let me know what would be the best way to tackle this!

Comment: you can try `df['your_column'].apply(func)` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: Since you are using numpy functions, have a look at numba too (https://numba.pydata.org/). It should work as such: `df['your_column'].apply(func, raw=True, engine='numba')`, provided that the numpy functions are compatible (https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html).

Comment: @notiv thanks for the suggestions! Unfortunately, it seems to take just as long to do these operations. Are such large datasets supposed to take 25-30 mins typically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see if helps with the timing.  I worry that it will take up to much memory.  I don't have the data to test.  You can try.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('01/01/2021','12/31/2021',freq='M'),columns=['Date'])
holidays = pd.to_datetime(np.array(['1/1/2021','12/25/2021','8/9/2021'])).to_numpy()
```

Assuming holidays: 1/1/2021, 8/9/2021, 12/25/2021

[image]

```
df['Days Away'] = ( 
    np.min(np.absolute(df.Date.to_numpy()
        .reshape(-1,1) - holidays),axis=1) / 
        np.timedelta64(1, 'D') 
    )
```

[image]

Comment: @KailashGautham  If this works for you, kindly check the tick mark to accept the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This is the code after I converted your code to use my variables. 
```testing_df['closest_public_holiday'] = ( 
    np.min(np.absolute(testing_df['date'].to_numpy().reshape(-1,1) - russian_public_holidays),axis=1) / 
        np.timedelta64(1, 'D') 
    )
```



However, I seem to be getting this weird error

```ufunc 'subtract' cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O')
```

Comment: are you able to do a Dtype for both the days and holidays and update the question ?

Comment: I've given you the codes I've used to create the data.  You could also do a dtype to compare the data type and see the difference between your data and mine.  Basically, have to do a conversion to the right type.  I suspect your holidays are in string, not coverted.

Comment: Also, do you have the link to the Kaggle dataset ?  Did you apply any other changes to the dataset and the holidays before you do this ?  If you are applying on raw data, then I can try on the dataset.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I'm not sure if I did this correctly. For the list of holidays I did "holidays.dtype" and it returned "dtype('O').  For the days column I got dtype('<M8[ns]')

Comment: About the dataset, you can find the data here. [link](https://www.kaggle.com/c/competitive-data-science-predict-future-sales#)

The holidays list was personally created by me and I used Pandas datetime to convert it to timestamps. The 'date' column from the data was in string format, and I again converted it using pandas datetime, so i dont see where the discrepancy is. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Can you create the holidays using my code in the answer?  It's working for me.

Comment: Edit: I converted the holidays list into the same type as the dates column. But in my testing dataframe I only have five dates, and the holidays list has 90 dates so it doesnt allow me to do the subtraction operation

Comment: I got the code to work! Now I will test on the actual dataset and see if there are any time improvements. Also, if the time DOES improve, I'd be very grateful if you could explain to me the logic behind why your code is faster. Thank you!

Comment: My code took 1 hour long, and yours took all of 3 seconds!!! I am simply amazed. Thank you so much, and if you could explain how it works, I'll try to incorporate this into my workflow in the future. I have also marked your answer as the correct one. It doesn't allow me to upvote since my reputation is lower than 15

Comment: You try to use the built in functions as much as possible, eg I used numpy.  Then your operations are all in C.  Python is written in C.  If you calculate in Python, then it's much slower.  I also see you are doing 1 loop to call a function and within the function, you loop again.  That would be very slow.  My suggestion is to get familiar with numpy and pandas and use the methods as much as possible.